# Multiple Galleries - fancyBox - MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, fancybox-2, mediawiki-extensions

I'm creating a tutorial using MediaWiki with the extension [FancyBoxThumbs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFancyBoxThumbs) enabled. The flow is something like this:

```
text for step 1
text for step 2
text for step n

<gallery>
image_for_step_1.png
image_for_step_2.png
image_for_step_n.png
</gallery>
```

So the user first read the steps, then see the print screens of how to do it.

The trouble is when i have more than one gallery in the same page. The slideshow goes through all the galleries, and my users get really confused seeing pictures of steps that were not yet explained. :S

What im trying to achieve was already covered in other questions here. Like in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/m8ynV/ , but, i have no idea on how to make it work in mediawiki.

If i could do something like this would be perfect.

```
<gallery id="1">
  //images here
</gallery>

<gallery id="2">
  //images here
</gallery>
```

But i am open to any kind of solution you might provide.

Im using mediawiki 1.19.15, PHP 5.2.6, and FancyBox v2

Comment: Just to clarify, which FancyBox extension is that? Is it https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FancyBoxThumbs? Or are you implementing FancyBox yourself through common.js or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, im using that extension. I did no modification on it so far

Comment: Then I think, from a quick look at it, that you will have to rewrite it, making a new extension for your needs. (I could be missing something)

Comment: For tutorials spread in steps etc., there is also [GuidedTour](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GuidedTour): is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nemo no, the guides i'm writing are about using another software (which is not web-based), so it won't help me

Comment: @DanielMK, I'm not sure this rules out GuidedTour, but I've not  used it extensively so I can't tell for sure.